# What is the best Server to host a Haskell webpage (HSP)?

Tags: haskell, webserver

I Need to set-up a server which can host a Haskell generated website. If I use PHP I can host it on a Apache sever. Likewise if I create a Haskell thing what are the suitable webservers I can use? I have tried several but most of then ended with an error. Please give me some details to set-up a Haskell running webserver.

**Main need is to create a dynamic website which based on Haskell programming language.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally haskell isn't served through an Apache module. You either set up a cgi or fcgi executable, and then use apache, nginix, etc. to call that, or you use a framework like snap or happstack that provides its own server. You then don't need apache, nginix, or whatever else unless you want to use it as a proxy (to provide https, for example).

For reference, see the web category at the Haskell wiki: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Web

Edit: for just running hsp, the hsp-cgi package works: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsp-cgi

And for a more robust way to run hsp (not involving launching the cgi executable on each request, allowing for more persistent state therefore, etc.) then happstack is your best bet, I think, since it has hsp integration built in.

Answer (score 5):

I'd take a look at [Yesod](http://docs.yesodweb.com/) or the [Snap Framework](http://snapframework.com/)

There's more discussion on the pros and cons of each on a [recent Reddit question](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/e7wiw/which_web_framework_should_i_use/).

Comment: I hope this will work. I can see the "Hello World" thing in my web browser. I will try other thing also. Thanks dude...!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell the Apache how to process haskell files in just the same way Apache passes php-files to the PHP interpreter. So, think of a file extension of your haskell files, then see the Apache documentation on filters/file-endings to tell it that such files should be passed through your favorite Haskell interpreter.

Comment: Is it possible to use Apache server to host a HSP. And if I'm using ghci what will be the configurations. Think i'm using a new stable apache sever without any changes to the original configurations. (on Fedora 12)

Comment: This is wrong. If you just pass through stuff, then you just get cgi, at best.